# Selenium - Не удалось войти в аккаунт Google, как быть?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, google-account

Пробую использовать Selenium для входа в аккаунт Google используя C#.

Столкнулся с проблемой (браузер открывается, драйвер используется, ввод логина вручную, chromedriver):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовал разные настройки, предложенные в ответах в сети, но проблема не решена.

```
        options.AddArgument("--disable-web-security");
        options.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Default");
        options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-plugins-discovery");
        options.AddArgument("--incognito");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-automation-extension");
        options.AddArgument("--enable-automation");
```

Авторизация по https://accounts.google.com/signin/, юзер агенты выставлялись - толку ноль.

Как можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: А при чем тут настройки браузера? Он проверяется в основном по UsertAgent и другим параметрам. Попробуйте просто его сменить. Также, зачем вам селениум вовсе, какую задачу решаете?

Comment: по смыслу похоже, что selenium не может перейти на https. По какому url происходит заход?

Comment: Url верный, юзер агент подставляется, он аналогично верный и это не решает задачу, увы. https://accounts.google.com/signin/

Comment: Пробовали запустить браузер селениумом, поставить точку останова после открытия страницы и дальше вручную сделать логин? Это чтобы проверит дело ли в браузере и настройках или в том, что скрипт выполняет действия очень быстро.

Comment: Я пробовал, то есть вебдрайвер открыл браузер, а я вручную ввел логин и сразу мне вот то что на скрине.